# Clean up SimplePing code with RunLoop.current.run

Tags: ios, swift

I found the [SimplePing](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html) library from Apple and want to use it in a SwiftUI Project.

To use the library I code online which works fine. The `start` function is as follows:

```
public func start(hostName: String) {
    
    let pinger = SimplePing(hostName: "192.168.178.20")
    pinger.delegate = self
    pinger.start()
    
    var count = 5
    repeat {
        if (self.canStartPinging) {
            pinger.send(with: nil)
            count-=1                
            if count == 0{
                self.canStartPinging = false
                break
            }
        }
        RunLoop.current.run(mode: RunLoop.Mode.default, before: NSDate.distantFuture)
    } while(true)
```

I don't really understand why I need the `RunLoop.current.run(mode: RunLoop.Mode.default, before: NSDate.distantFuture)` line. When I remove it the delegates of SimplePing doesn't get called.

How can I simplify this code and use it without blocking the Main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `run(mode:before:)` is there to allow the run loop to process events while this `repeat`-`while` loop spins. It’s a way to make a blocking loop allow things to occur on the run loop.

You haven’t shared the code that is setting `canStartPinging`, but I’m guessing that, at the very least, `SimplePingDelegate` method `didStartWithAddress` sets it. So, if you’re spinning on the main thread without calling that `run(mode:before:)`, the `SimplePing` delegate method probably never gets a chance to be called. By adding that `run` call, at least the delegate method can run.

Your suspicion about this this whole pattern of spinning and calling `run(mode:before:)` is warranted. It’s horribly inefficient pattern. It should be eliminated.

If this were a standard Swift project, I’d suggest just using the delegate-protocol pattern and you’d be done. Since this is Swift UI, I’d suggest refactoring this to be a Combine [`Publisher`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher), which you can then integrate into your SwiftUI project.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, i will try to refactor it into a Publisher. Thanks!

Comment: @JulianBeck - I took a crack at it [here](https://github.com/robertmryan/SimplePing). I basically translated the `SimplePing` delegate methods into an enumeration and created a publisher that emits them.